# Не могу пропинговать ip роутера с виртуальной машины openwrt?

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint, openwrt

Я приложил схему своего задания по предмету в универе. В общем, с хоста я могу пинговать vboxnet, wan (192.168.1.2), но не могу пинговать lan (192.168.10.1), но с хоста пингуется роутер. Когда захожу в openWRT(используя virtualbox), то в нем не пингуется роутер. Также приложил снимок настройки сети в openwrt. Хост - Linux Cinnamon Mint 20.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] В чем может быть проблема? Уже голову себе сломал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На virtualbox у виртуалки какой тип сетевого адаптера выбран? Чтобы виртуалка встроилась в реальную сеть, адаптер должен быть "мостовое соединение" (bridged network)

Comment: Откуда у вас два основных шлюза (gateway)?

Comment: Адаптеры настроены: адаптер 1 - виртуальный адаптер хоста, адаптер 2 - внутренняя сеть. Так должно быть настроено по заданию

Comment: Как понять откуда 2 основных шлюза? Немножко не понял суть вопроса